Cartoon about animals playing American Football
I am looking for this cartoon movie that aired on HBO between 1997 and 2005. The whole movie is about a bear quarterback that gets framed for a crime and can't play. The whole time he is running from 2 alligator security guards. I do remember the announcers were a bulldog and a parrot and they even had fake commercials. I do know if it was made in Russia and was never published in the USA. I really want to find the name. 

It was on HBO, made in Russia and never published in the USA? What do mean by published? Was it a Russian version of HBO? Do mean released on video? Do you mean it was based on a Russian comic or something?

Here's a place to start, until someone can answer your question: http://www.animator.ru/db/?ver=eng&p=films

I believe you are looking for the animated movie "Animal Wars", created in Russia and billed as the only animated lampoon of American Football. 
It was made in 2000, runs for 75 minutes, and can be viewed on Vimeo here. It is described on Rotten Tomatoes:

In this humorous animated feature for the family, a bear makes the local football team, but when he's accused of throwing a game for money, he's kicked off the squad. Depressed, the bear next sets out to prove to the team that he can still be trusted.

